# struts 2 password preset value

Tags: struts2

i want set preset value in struts 2 password tag, can anybody tell me advance for thanks

Answer (score 5):

for presetting value of any component all you need to do is set value attribute to whatever value you want or keep the name attribute equal to the bean property name in the calling action. this works as the value attribute is set to the name attribute by default.

For password there is one other thing you need to do i.e- set showPassword attribute of password component to true. it will then show the password in the masked form